# Coordinate ring of the complement to the theta divisor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves, plane-curves

Let $C$ be a smooth projective curve over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\Theta$ be the theta divisor in $J^{g-1}(C)$. The theta divisor is ample, so $J^{g-1}\setminus \Theta$ is affine. What is coordinate ring $R$ of this affine variety
$$
J^{g-1}\setminus \Theta = \operatorname{Spec} R.
$$

Is there a concrete description of $R$?

I'm mostly interested in the special case of a smooth plane quartic: $C \subset \mathbb{P}^2$, $\deg C =4$ and thus $g(C)=3$.